# Can We add More than 10 columns to a table with single Query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi i want to add 30 columns to a table with name `UserDef1` - `UserDef30` and in that

```
UserDef1 - UserDef15 (datetype is nvarchar)
UserDef16-UserDef20 (money)
UserDef21 - UserDef25 (date)
UserDef26 - UserDef30 (Bit)
```

the above have to be done with the single Query instead of Writing the following line for 30 times

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserDeftab ADD UserDef1 nvarchar(Max) NULL DEFAULT(Null)
GO
```

Can we Do that?

Comment: I assume userdef is short for "user defined". Are you sure that this approach is the right one? What if a user wants to define a 6th money value? At this point, switching to e.g. a single XML column might be more productive and not artificially restrict users.

Answer (score 0):

> have to be done with the single Query instead of Writing the following
>   line for 30 times

Just separate each column you want to add with a `,`.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserDeftab ADD
  UserDef1 nvarchar(Max) NULL,
  UserDef2 nvarchar(Max) NULL,
  UserDef3 nvarchar(Max) NULL,
  UserDef4 nvarchar(Max) NULL,
  UserDef16 money NULL,
  UserDef21 date NULL,
  UserDef26 bit NOT NULL
```